# How can one have webpack watch and run after a build

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a very simple program, I would like webpack or a webpack plugin to restart it after every bundle change.  I am not running a web server so this the reason I'm not using `webpack-dev-server`.

I imagine a plugin like this but with process management:

```
function CompilerDone() {}
CompilerDone.prototype.apply = function(compiler) {
    compiler.plugin('done', function() {
        // exec node ./bundle.js
    })
}
```

This could get tricky.  Do you know of a better way?

Comment: You should use watch mode of webpack

Answer (score 0):

Use a different process to watch the webpack bundle:

```
npm i nodemon --save-dev
nodemon bundle
```